# doctrine:build --forms --model doesn't generate specific filter form

Tags: forms, symfony1, filter, schema.yml

I have a schma.yml file with a variety of tables. For one single table, the doctrine:build command doesn't build a formfilter class

The schema.yml definition of the table is

```
InactiveReason:
  actAs:
    Sortable: ~
  columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, unique: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    name: { type: string(100), notnull: true }
```

Both model and form classes are generated, however I can't get it to generate the formfilter classes (both InactiveReasonFormFilter and BaseInactiveReasonFormFilter)

I have tried moving around the definition in schema.yml, which didn't help either. Am I using some sort of reserved keywore here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying for the build task to generate the filter classes

```
doctrine:build --forms --model
```

Add on the --filters option or replace all options with the --all-classes option

```
doctrine:build --forms --model --filters

doctrine:build --all-classes
```

Comment: Cheers, this is the first project were I can't quite use build:all -- and-load